# Problem with saveOrUpdate() in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Recently i am started using hibernate. to insert or update i am using `saveOrUpdate()` function.
If i update an entry i works fine. But, with new entry hibernate generate a Query. Buts nothing gets updated in the table.

My scenario is like this,

i am using Many to One & One to Many relationship between two tables`[Expense, Category]`
For update or insert, i am creating two objects`(Expense expense, Category category)` from the
client side. In the server side, i set `category` object with `expense` object.

```
public void upDateExpenseTable(Expens expense, Category category) {

    expense.setCategory(category);
    Session session = Main.getSession();
    try{
        System.out.println("Inside Update Try Block");
        session = Main.getSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(expense);
        tr.commit();

    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Object structure is like, `catogery.catId, category.catName` & 
`expense.expnsId, expense.expnsName, expense.amount, expense.status, expense.userName`.

But there is another one column in `Expense` Table `cat_id`. Its is through mapping annotation. But i dont have any property for that in Expense entity. 
When inserting new data, i am not giving any Id.

Any suggestions!!!

```
public class Expens implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int expnsId;
private int amount;
private String date;
private String status;
private String userName;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cat_id") 
private Category category;
    //Setter Getter

}
```

**Category Classs**

```
public class Category{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int catId;
private String catName;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Expens.class, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Expens> expenses;
}//Setters Getters ommited.
```

Comment: The statement that Category is mapped through an annotation but there is no property on the Expense Entity does not make any sense.  Could you post the actual annotated entities?  May help clear things up.

Comment: @Affe: Now the code is updated in Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood everything but I can at least tell you that you're not building your bi-directional association correctly, you need to set *"both sides of the link"* when building your object graph:

```
...
expense.setCategory(category);
category.getExpenses().add(expense);
...
session.saveOrUpdate(category);
```

And this is usually done in "link management" methods, like this (in `Category`):

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int catId;
    private String catName;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Expens.class, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Expens> expenses = new ArrayList<Expens>();

    public void addToExpenses(Expense expense) {
        expenses.add(expense);
        expense.setCategory(this);
    }    

    protected List getExpenses() { // protected to prevent direct access from outside the hierarchy
        return expenses;
    }

    protected void setExpenses(List expenses) { // protected to prevent direct access
        this.expenses = expenses;
    }

    //...
}
```

And the code becomes:

```
category.addToExpenses(expense);
session.saveOrUpdate(category);
```

Funnily enough (or not), I've written about this three times today.

#### Resource

- Hibernate Core Documentation

  - [1.2.6. Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir)

Comment: The problem is not yet solved. i had other works to finish. I dont think i can able to understand it on my own. Now i ve got backup. My boss, will do this things practically to train me. I thought to understand it on my own. But, no prob... Anyway thanks man, thanks for your reply. :)